# Stuck in a Context-Free Proof

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I am trying to work through the pumping lemma for CFLs.

$L_1 = \{0^n 1^{mn} : n,m \in \Bbb N\}$

I am trying to find a contradiction. 
I have currently chosen $z= 0^p1^{2p}$ to be my string. 
Then
$|z| \geq p$ where  $p$ is the pumping length.

I know $z = uvwxy$. So that $|vwx| \leq p$ and $|vx| \geq 1$.

Case 1.  $vwx$ is all 0s.

This would result in many more 0s being added and an i can be chosen such that
$uv^iwx^iy$ results in too many zeros. 
$0^{p+j+k}1^{2p}$

Case 2.
$vwx$ is all 1s. In this case chose $i=0$, so that the number of 1s decrease by at least 1. This would no longer be divisible into $n$ and $m$.

case 3.

It is a mix of 1s and 0s. 
I am not sure how to proceed here.

I have been trying to do a variety of types of CFL proofs but, I seem to get muddled up in the same spot every time. Some advice or point in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: Note, for instance, that if $v$ or $x$ have both 1s and 2s, then easily you can get out of the language.

Comment: Thank you, but I am still unsure of if I am going down the right track or not. Would 3 cases be sufficient to break it up into?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "1s and 0s". And more precisely, by taking $i=2$ is enough in this subcase, because you would have a 010 pattern. So $v$ is made of 0s and $x$ is made of the 1s, and $w$ might have both. This is the only subcase missing.

Comment: If you actually succeeded in solving the problem, you should consider posting your own answer (and accepting it).

Answer (score 1):

You have chosen the wrong word. I would have chosen $0^{p+1}1^{(p+1)^2}$ instead.

For it we have the same three cases and the same proofs for the cases 1 and 2.

If the case 3 is true, then $uv^iwx^iy = 0^{p + 1 + |v|(i - 1)}1^{(p + 1)^2 + |x|(i - 1)}$.

That means, that $\forall i \in \mathbb{N}$ $\frac{(p + 1)^2 + |x|(i - 1)}{p + 1 + |v|(i - 1)} \in \mathbb{N}$.

On the other hand, $\lim_{i \to \infty} \frac{(p + 1)^2 + |x|(i - 1)}{p + 1 + |v|(i - 1)} = \frac{|x|}{|v|}$.

Thus, as $\mathbb{N}$ is nowhere dense, $\exists n \in \mathbb{N} \forall i > n \frac{(p + 1)^2 + |x|(i - 1)}{p + 1 + |v|(i - 1)} = \frac{|x|}{|v|}$, which is only possible, when $\frac{|x|}{|v|} = p + 1$.

From this we get $p + 1 = \frac{|x|}{|v|} \leq |x| \leq |vwx| \leq p$, which leads us to the contradiction.